# freeswitch enterprise originate - how to determine if all failed

Tags: freeswitch

I'm originating multiple sequential calls on freeswitch

```
originate {continue_on_fail=true,originate_continue_on_timeout=true,originate_timeout=20,ignore_early_media=true}[record_number=abcd,campaign=test-presidio,idbrand=2]sofia/gateway/c-gw-1/yyyyy|[record_number=efgh,campaign=test-presidio,idbrand=2]sofia/gateway/c-gw-1/xxxxxxx &park()
```

I'm using the bgapi.

is there an event that is raised when the originate command has processed all calls ? Is there a way to determine if all calls failed ?

thx

Answer (score 1):

This question is a little dated, but a note here...

NEVER EVER process calls like this if you are running a dialer (like the OP seems to be doing). This will just cause you heartache, as it is not a clean way to originate calls especially if there are hundreds of calls being sent. You need to be running these in seperate threads (i.e. seperate calls altogether). You can limit calls in your ESL/XML-RPC client if needed.

This is also invalid syntax for an enterprise originate. ':_:' should be used instead of '|'.

Comment: hi brian, why do you suggest it is not a clean way of generating calls ?

Comment: For starters, on the first successful call you'd be cancelling any other calls you're passing through that command.

Comment: Hi Brian, syntax is correct. Plz note documentation stating :" Each dial string can have its own {} and [] blocks and can themselves be simultaneous or sequential (containing ',' or '|')" . The :_: is for mulitple calls is separate threads. Not my case. Thank you anyways, I don't think that in this case cancelling calls would occur.

Comment: In this case, 'sequential' means that it will try one endpoint at a time, and if the call isn't picked up it will try the next. 'Simultaneous' tries all endpoints at once. As soon as one endpoint is answered, all other tries for all other endpoints will be hung up with LOSE_RACE (or similar reason). '{}' and '[]' refer to setting variables for specific channels (or all channels at once if you wish). Also worth noting, if you're going to cite documentation, you should also do us a favor and give us a link. Luckily, I'm familiar enough with the docs to answer this one for you.

Comment: hi brian, the difference between sequential and simultaneous is clear in the documentation ( plz refer to bridge command https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/bridge) . My question was about **sequential** calls and and if there existed an event that would be fired if all calls originating sequentially from a single bridge command failed.

Comment: That's because you mentioned enterprise originate in the title of the thread. Enterprise originate fires of calls to the destination simultaneously and not sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing this directly into cli? Or are you using XMLRPC? Or are you using an ESL? In the latter two scenarios, you can send off your calls and check those calls as they're in-progress. Your language of choice should let you use error checking to find out what happens and how many calls were successful vs. failed, etc..